# Query hangs when executed second time

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I am biulting a register system. I use node, express and my database is PostgreSQL. I use the latest [pg module](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) to communicate with Postgre.

My user-getting function is multipurpose, gets a user based on its id or its username. (back-end)

```
User.get = function (info,t, fn){
    var text;
    if(t=="id"){
        text = "SELECT user.id, user.usrnm FROM user WHERE user.id=$1";             
    }
    else{
        text = "SELECT user.id, user.usrnm, user.role FROM user WHERE user.usrnm=$1";
    }

    var query = client.query({ text:text, values:[info]}, function(err, result){
        if(err) {return fn(err);}
        query.on("row", function (row, result) {                   
            result.addRow(row);
        });
        if(result.rows.length==0){//no user found
            return fn(err, null);
            query.on("end", function(){client.end();});
        }
        if(t=="id"){
            return fn(null, new User({
                        id:result.rows[0].id,
                        usrnm:result.rows[0].usrnm
                    })
            );
            query.on("end", function(){clientGuest.end();});
        }
        else{
            return fn(null, new User({
                        id:result.rows[0].id,
                        usrnm:result.rows[0].usrnm,
                        role:result.rows[0].role
                    })
            );      
            query.on("end", function(){clientGuest.end();});    
        }       
    });
    query.on("end", function(){clientGuest.end();});    
}
```

So, I use the above to check if there is a user already using a username. If not, I save the new user (register.) (front-end)

```
    User.get(username, "name", function(error, user){
        if(error) return next(err);
        if(user!=null){//so, we found a user
            res.error("Username already in use");
            res.redirect('back');
            res.end();
        }
        else{
            user = new User ({
                usrnm:username,
                pswrd:userpass
            });

            user.save(function(err){
                if(err) return next(err);
                req.session.uid=user.id;                                
            })
            res.redirect('/');
            res.end();
        }           

    })  
});
```

Whether I insert a unique username or one that is already used, the first time all works well, The second time, the data are sent to the `User.get`, and after that the exacution hangs.

I put several `console.log` inside the query and only one gives data back. The one right after `User.get = function (info,t, fn){`that show the value of `t` and `info`. All the other `console.log` show nothing.

I dont know how to fix this. Maybe its a detail I dont get. Plaese help.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it is the query hangs and not your web server? See possible related issue:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521804/pg-promise-hangs-after-six-queries. And if it is related to node-postgres, check out [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), it is much easier to use.

Comment: @vitaly-t Check out my answer and please comment if I got it right. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I changed my user get function to this

```
User.get = function (info,t, fn){

var text;
if(t=="id"){
    text = "SELECT user.id, user.usrnm FROM user WHERE user.id=$1";             
}
else{
    text = "SELECT user.id, user.usrnm, user.role FROM user WHERE user.usrnm=$1";
}   
var query = client.query({ text:text, values:[info]}, function(err, result){  if(err) {return fn(err);} });
    query.on("row", function (row, result) {                   
        result.addRow(row);
    });

query.on("end", function(result){                       
    if(result.rows.length==0){return fn(null);}
    if(t=="id"){
        return fn( new User({
                     id:result.rows[0].id,
                     usrnm:result.rows[0].usrnm
                })
        );
    }
    else{
        return fn( new User({
                      id:result.rows[0].id,
                      usrnm:result.rows[0].usrnm,
                      role:result.rows[0].role
                })
        );      
    }                                                       
    client.end();
});
```

}

So `query.on row` is simple and adds rows. When we are sure that the query is finished, `query.on("end"` takes action and counts the rows, deciding what to return.

I guess my problem was that the checking or rows and the `t` value was outside the `query.on end` , so it is possible that data were send before the query was finished or the opposite, the query finished before any data send, depending on the time the query needed to search for data, bring them back and add them to the `result`.